# SQLite prepare method fails due to syntax error

Tags: database, perl, sqlite

So I want to create a database for Users and insert values into the fields using variable. Initially I tried using it calling the do function, but it wasn't reading the variables properly so I decided to just use prepare and execute separately. This is my code:

```
$dbh->do("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users");
$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE Users(
zid TEXT, 
Name TEXT, 
Email TEXT, 
password TEXT, 
Mates TEXT, 
Program TEXT, 
Courses TEXT, 
Suburb TEXT, 
Birthday TEXT)");

$zid = "z33432523";
$name = "John Doe";
$email = "email@gmail.com";
$password = "alien";
$mates = "z3459148 z3458291";
$program = "";
$courses = "";
$suburb = "";
$birthday = "13/5/1992";

$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?. ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$sth->execute($zid, $name, $email, $password, $mates, $program, $courses, $suburb, $birthday);
$dbh->disconnect();
```

However, if I try running this code I get the following error:

```
DBD::SQLite::db prepare failed: near ".": syntax error at ./dbm.pl line 35.
```

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is?

Comment: If you get an error that mentions a '.' in your SQL, then perhaps you should start by searching your SQL for dots :-)

Comment: @DaveCross haha this is embarrassing...... thank you

Comment: Don't sweat over a dot. That happens to all of us. ;) On a different note, it looks like your column `Mates` is supposed to hold IDs of the friends of that user. If you put several relations into one column your database design is _unnormalized_, which for a relational database is a bad decision. It would be smarter to create another table, e.g. `Users_Mates` with columns `relation_id`, `user_id` and `mate_id`. Now you can have one record for each relationship (in the most literal sense)...

Comment: ... Those are easy to fetch, you can join on them directly, and your database is normalized. Read up on it on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization or listen to your teacher I guess, it's gonna be up next most likely. ;-)

Comment: @simbabque aaah!! thank you~ i'm still in the early stages of this assignment but i definitely think that'll come in useful later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
near ".": syntax error

INSERT INTO Users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?. ?, ?, ?, ?)
                                       ^
```